# displaying custom error message when .mov doesn't play PHP

Tags: php, html, firefox, .mov

trying to get firefox to play this .mov file.
I've tried a few things including looking here on stack. Can't get it to work in Firefox, 
SO, I wanted to display a custom error when you play the movie in FireFox instead of the gray broken video file image.

Suggestions?

Here's the code that doesn't work in firefox

```
function videoPlayer($videoPath, $height, $width){

$videoPath = "../videos/redhand.mov";

$height = 320;
$width = 400;

echo "<video height='".$height."' width='".$width."' controls autoplay>
   <source src='" . $videoPath  . "' type='video/mp4'>
<object CLASSID='clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B' height='".$height."' width='".$width."' CODEBASE=' http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab'>
    <param name='src' value='" . $videoPath  . "'>
    <param name='qtsrc' value='" . $videoPath  . "'>
    <param name='autoplay' value='true'>
    <param name='loop' value='false'>
    <param name='controller' value='true'>
    <embed src='" . $videoPath  . "' qtsrc='" . $videoPath  . "'  width='320' height='256' autoplay='true' loop='false' controller='true' pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/'></embed>

    </video>";


}


videoPlayer("../videos/redhand.mov", 500, 500);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
if($browser['browser']) == "Firefox") {
     enter code here
} else {
     enter code here
}
```

Reference; http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.get-browser.php